# Adjusting p-values of multiple correlations

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I do a correlation test in r with `cor.test` over two matrices, M and A, the final correlation matrix is C. The `cor.test` provides a p-value or estimate.

How should I correct for multiple testing the p-values provided?

If I use `p.adjust(unlist(C), "fdr")` then all the p-values are used for correcting, and I think that this overestimate the number of test done with the same data. But I might be wrong

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5, 20)
M <- matrix(rnorm(100), 20, 5)
result <- apply(A, 1, function(x){
     apply(M, 2, function(y){
   cor.test(x, y, method = "pearson")
  })
})
C <- sapply(result, function(x){
sapply(x, function(y){
    y$p.value
  })
})
```

Comment: Why do you think that all the p-values should not be adjusted?

Comment: I think that they should be adjusted but not taking all the p-values generated as the population of p-values, because I didn't test the same on all of them. I am inclined to do and adjustment for each column of the C matrix, as it would adjust the multiple testing of the same p-values for one column in M, as it was done to calculate them

Comment: @IIrs I think your answer makes sense. But why not correct p values on each *row*?

Comment: @WCMC And why not on each *column* ? If the resulting matrix has not the same dimensions by column than by rows this results on different correlations selected. Depending on the correction and which is longer some correlations will be filtered out.